# Pandas making a new list from groupby object

Tags: loops, dataframe, append, pandas-groupby

My data has a country column and 'Clicked on Ad' column which has boolean value for customers preference for ad. I want to groupby my list to see the number of clicks based on countries. Then I want to cut (4,8) clicks which represent highest clicks per country. I want to cut these rows and create a new list while keeping all features of rows

```
ad_country=ad_data.groupby('Country')  
Country_sum=[]  
for i in range(4,8):  
    if ad_country['Clicked on Ad']==i:  
        Country_sum.append(iloc[ad_country])
```

SAMPLE

Daily >>>>> Age  >>Daily Internet Usage   >>>    Country    >>>>  Clicked on Ad(Boolean)
68.95   >>>>>>35    >>>>>>  256.09              >>>>>>>>>     Tunisia>>>>>>>>>>>>    0
75,78>>>>>>28>>>>>>>>214.9>>>>>>>>>>Mexico>>>>>>>>>>>>1

My result should have a Dataframe containing rows with Country names as index, while having total clicked on ad feature totals and other features(though not important for analysis) totals values in the columns.

Comment: Please show a sample of your data and the output expected.

Answer (score 0):

ad_country=ad_data.groupby('Country')['Clicked on Ad'].sum()

I could get a country lists using groupby and sum(). I can also see max sample size w count()

I am still looking to find if I can slice a groupby object for max counts like value_counts().